# spread a file into multiple .csv files per each line of inputfile read

Tags: command-line, scripts, text-processing, awk, csv

I have .csv file with over 1000 rows that contains on each row a number ie, "2224441214" that is the only value on the row. I need to break that file up into a .csv file named "2224441214.csv" for each row.

ie, "2224441214.csv" "22655443.csv" "2222211564.csv"

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to provide a few verbatim rows from your input so we can see what you're actually dealing with? It's not clear where this these row numbers actually are.

Comment: Its rather simple, Each row has 1 column with a number. I just need a .csv file for each number in the cell...
2277933696
2278001130
2278025610
2278206304
2278984216
2280632844
2282153588
2283260326
2283541669
10000009194
10000010217
 is what is would look like when you open it. If it is opened in a spreadsheet it is only column a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done with below awk command,

```
awk '{print > $0".csv"}' infile.csv
```

This will create multi .csv files named with numbers read from infile.csv